# Simulating clicks, focus, and data entry by JAVASCRIPT (ONLY && incl. jQuery if required) such that the website thinks it's an actual human operator?

Tags: javascript, jquery, automation, user-input, simulation

Is there a way to simulate user clicks, focus, and data entry on a website by JAVASCRIPT (ONLY && including jQuery if required) such that the website truly believes that it is an actual human operator at work?

I do not want to use a third party software and I have already tried the following methods to no avail:

1. `jQuery's $('#input-field').click()`
2. `var press = $.Event("keypress");
           press.bubbles = true;
           press.cancelable = true;
           press.charCode = 97;
           press.currentTarget = $("#_eo_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_XX")[0];
           press.eventPhase = 2;
           press.keyCode = 97;
           press.returnValue = true;
           press.srcElement = $("#_eo_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_XX")[0];
           press.target = $("#_eo_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_XX")[0];
           press.type = "keypress";
           press.view = Window;
           press.which = 97;
           press`
3. `$("#_eo_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_XX").mousedown(function() {  console.log("mousedown"); })
                     .mouseup(function() { console.log("mouseup"); })
                     .click(function() { console.log("click"); return false; });`

3.1

```
$('#_eo_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_XX').val('18/04/2014');
```

3.2 `$('#_eo_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_XX').trigger('blur');`

1. `function eventFire(el, etype){
             if (el.fireEvent) {
               (el.fireEvent('on' + etype));
             } else {
               var evObj = document.createEvent('Events');
               evObj.initEvent(etype, true, false);
               el.dispatchEvent(evObj);
             }
           }eventFire(document.getElementById('_eo_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_XX'),'click')`

Thanks :-)

Comment: What are you tried to achieve? It is testing or something else

Comment: It's not clear from the numbered list you provided what you actually tried, but the short answer to your question is yes... as far as form inputs, clicks on DOM elements, keypresses, and the like go. Some test frameworks are built on top of this kind of JavaScript programmable interaction, in fact.